# How to delete current app from project in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I tried out new version of Firebase. 
I have created new project. Added there necessary apps. After that I added the test app, which I don't need any more. But I could not find a button that can remove this test application without deleting the entire project.

[image: how to delete app?]

Answer (score 36):

You can delete apps from a project via **Project Settings > Select App > Advanced Options > Delete this app** on the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com).

Comment: For me importing from a Google project created some oddly named Android apps that don't actually exists. It will nice when this is available.

Comment: But now its possible to delete an app from a project.. Time to update your answer.. :)

Comment: For me the "Delete this app" button wasn't visible when using Safari. With Chrome everything worked as described.

Answer (score 12):

Please note : This is about deleting a Project, which I was unable to do so. So I have posted my steps which may help others. I have successfully deleted my project.
1) Click on the Project which you want to delete.Then you will see the below screenshot.[image: Then click on the setting icon just beside your project]

Now follow the screen as attached
[image]

then scroll down and you will have the option to delete the project.
[image]

Comment: I guess its "Delete Project" and not "Delete App". try to click on it, you will see a popup in Red saying "This is a permanent action. All apps contained within this project will also be deleted." :)

Comment: ya its about "Deleting Project". I have mentioned in my first line itself as "Please note : This is about deleting a Project".

Comment: and regarding deleting a particular "App" in a Project, its not there as of now. May be we can see in near future.

Comment: I just spend the last 10 min trying to find this button. The UX of this platform is absolutely horrible.

Comment: @henritroyat for a first time user, its a bit tricky. But once you play around with it, you will be more familiar to it.

Comment: Deleting the project doesn't displace it which is kind of unwanted. Probably it will take some time before the project completely disappear but I couldn't find any information regarding this in the documentation.

Comment: Why the downvote. I clearly tried to explain my answer in which context I am speaking.

Answer (score 5):

At the bottom there is an Advance menu. There is the  <kbd>DELETE THIS APP</kbd>  button.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

you can delete app as well as project, option can be change at any time depends on fire base (02/10/2017)

go to fire base console click on **project** that you wants to delete click on **setting** icon on left top,

select **Project settings** go down to bottom, and you can see **DELETE PROJECT** button.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Confirming the earlier answers provided, here's a detailed step-by-step.

1. Go to Project settings. (Alternatively, from the home screen of the Project View, click on the  <kbd>...</kbd>  (Settings button on the right side of the app's name), then click  <kbd>MANAGE</kbd> .
2. Under ***Your Apps*** section, select the app you want to delete.
3. Click on ***Advanced Options***.
4. Click on  <kbd>DELETE THIS APP</kbd> , A note will be shown:

   > Caution, this is a permanent action. Deleting your app will delete the corresponding Analytics data, but not your app's API keys or OAuth clients.
5. Click on  <kbd>DELETE THIS APP PERMANENTLY</kbd>

A prompt will be displayed on the upper right corner of your Console would show up confirming the deletion.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to setting of project
   [image]
2. Copy project ID[image]
3. Click on a delete project at the bottom.

[image]

4. Enter Project ID and delete project.
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: From "Project Overview" select settings of the app you want to delete.

[image: Step 1]

Step 2: Click "Delete This App" button on the bottom of your app details.

[image: Step 2]

Comment: For me, this button is not there in safari but appears in google chrome under the same account.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the feature has been added. Project settings > select the app > Advanced Options > Delete this app

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can delete delete current app from project in Firebase, here i how to do that (setting->perission->all projects) :

[image]

[image]

Comment: and it will be waiting for deletion

Answer (score 0):

You must delete all Role except Owner in Manage Permission in console.firebase.google.com before delete current app from project in Firebase

Answer (score 0):

We can delete project who is having permission.

1. Only owner of project can delete it.
2. Even empty project also can be
       deleted by only owner.
   To delete/ remove project you need to shutdown and then delete it will take time as per your project size.

steps:

Go to Projet overview click on (gear icon) > Settings > Advanced
opens new window:
Google cloud platform > manage resources> Select project and click on delete

Answer (score 0):

Go the console project list, click on the project,

tap on the project overview at the sidebar section, you will find delete project at the bottom of section

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Delete an app
Sign in to Firebase, then open your project.
Click the Left Side Menu ->**Project Overview** [image]Settings icon, then select **Project settings**.
Then Scroll Down the **Your apps** card,
Under the Your apps card,
click Delete project open popup.
Check that the desired app is being deleted, then click Delete Project app permanently.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Gear Icon near top left -> Project Settings -> Delete Project (in the middle below "your apps" container).

Comment: it's not about deleting project, but removing a single app from a project

Comment: OP is confused. You can only have one DB per project.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/Khy0dpKYB_0

There are no apps per project in Firebase. You can tell from all the other answers and the lack of a marked solution that people are confused by the question. Also, multiple people have given the same response I gave, so I don't deserve -5 reputation points for this answer.

Comment: The answer above this one is the same answer and it has 9 points upvoted.