# Deleting Firebase projects

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

Can someone tell me how to properly request projects are deleted from Firebase. I am at the project limit and scheduled a few old ones for deletion on about December 22nd. Obviously well in excess of 7 days have past and I still can not create a new project. What am I missing?

Comment: Please [reach out to Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I have already done this and it didn't work. I thought someone here might know how to do something apparently simple like remove a project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete current app from project in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399681/how-to-delete-current-app-from-project-in-firebase)

Comment: If you delete a project, the project is _soft deleted_ and the owner can restore the project within 30 days. Until the 30 days passed, a soft deleted project still counts against the project quota. See https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#managing_project_quotas

Answer (score 3):

Click on the gear icon next to "Project Overview" and select "Project Settings" >> 
Then scroll down to the bottom of the page and you'll see "Delete project" >>
After clicking it you will see a popup with checkboxes you have to check all to be able to delete and you are allowed to restore the project in 30 days.

Comment: what if I cannot see this button?

Comment: @ André Ramon : it's there.