# How to remove Google project from Firebase Console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console, google-console-developer

I've project on [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and I've added this here on [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/). Now I've been forced to use Firebase Analytics instead of Google Analytics. So I want to remove/unlink my project back from firebase console only.

If I delete the project from [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), then project will also be deleted from [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). What's the problem!

Please provide any solution.

Comment: Refer this site [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399681/how-to-delete-current-app-from-project-in-firebase) Very good explanation given here.

Comment: I'm asking to delete project not the app

Comment: @Khan did you ever get an answer to this question? I'm thinking the answer is that you cannot "unlink firebase" / "disable the Firebase API's" in order to remove the project from the Firebase UI.

Comment: @JWAspin ~5 years ago when I raised this issue, I couldn't find any resolution around that time. But I believe, Google would have introduced something to overcome this problem therefore these gentle people are answering. :)

Comment: Hello @Khan when you get the answer please let us know. I am bookmarking this question.

Comment: Looks like no answer is working for you :(

Answer (score 27):

Go to https://console.firebase.google.com/
Click on project which you want tot delete.
Go to Project settings.
Scroll down and click on delete Project.

Comment: You didn't read question I think. If I delete the project from Firebase Console, then project will also be deleted from Google Developer Console.

Answer (score 17):

You can also delete a project this way:

1) Go to your console and select the project you would like to delete. Then, go to "Users permissions" located under the settings gear/widget:
[image]

2)Then the page will open up to the "settings: users and permissions" tab by default. You will need to navigate to the "general" tab. At the bottom of the page you will see a grey easily missable button labeled "Delete", click, read, and accept a few terms and conditions that you may actually want to read and not skim over:

[image]

I tried deleting via the GCP console but for some reason it did not work for me. It would tell me it was deleting the project, and confirmed deletion. I would go to the console and it would "be like" ..."Hey, just kidding, still here".

Answer (score 5):

> Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager
>
> Then select your project and click on delete.

[image]

> Then type the project ID given there and click on SHUT DOWN.

[image]

> Finally it will be pending for deletion within 30 days.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## **At 2020**

Simply open the project you want to delete then ,
As it written on [google support](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9137886?hl=en)

1. At the bottom of the General settings page, click  Delete project.
2. Select each checkbox to acknowledge the effects of deleting your project.
3. Click Delete project.

You should see something like:

[image]

Comment: So finally they have planned to provide the feature! Great!
Will try once and then mark this as the right answer. Thanks

Comment: won't solve op question because you cannot press "delete project" if you don't tick all the checkboxes. Those are just for confirming you are aware of the implications of deleting a project.

Answer (score 2):

To delete a firebase project, follow these steps:

step 1: **Go to console**

step 2: **select the project** to delete

step 3: select **settings** in the sidebar

step 4: select **project settings**

step 5: **scroll down** and select **delete project**

Hope you will find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1** -> Go to Firebase console

**Step 2** -> Select firebase project where your project is added

**Step 3** ->And click your project list and select your project name on click setting.

**Step 4** -> scroll down option is Delete project OR Remove this app

*I hope this is helpful thanks.*